# nodejs html rendering string instead of html

Tags: html, node.js

I'm getting started with nodejs. I dont undestand why my html page is not rendering as html my obj.

indexAction.js

```
const { list } = require('../../services/contacts');

const tpl = (contact) =>
  `
  <tr>
    <td>${contact.name}</td>
    <td>${contact.phoneNumber}</td>
    <td>${contact.fullName}</td>
  </tr>
  `;

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  const contacts = await list();

  console.log(contacts);

  const listItems =
    contacts.length > 0
      ? contacts.map(tpl).join('\n')
      : `<tr><td> colspan="4"> No contacts available</td></tr>`;

  console.log(listItems);
  
  return res.render('index', { listItems });
};
```

index.html

```
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/index.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class='pageName'>Index page</h1>
    <br />
    <div>
      <p>Contacts List</p>
    </div>
    <div id='divList'>
      {{listItems}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

html page:
[image]

I am expecting listItems to be rendered as html instead of a string.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js isn't doing that.

You are using some *unspecified template language*. It looks like Handlebars so I'm going to assume it is.

Look at [the documentation](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#html-escaping)

> Because it was originally designed to generate HTML, Handlebars escapes values returned by a `{{expression}}`. If you don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use the "triple-stash", `{{{`.

---

That said, you should move your HTML generating logic to Handlebars instead of doing it in JavaScript (where you are failing to escape any special characters that might appear in your data, which renders you vulnerable to XSS attacks).

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked. Yes, I’m  using hbs. What do you mean by move my logic to handlebars?

Comment: You've written JavaScript which loop over an array of data and generates a table row for each item in that array. Instead, pass the array to Handlebars and write Handlebars code to loop over it etc etc.